# Sum of datagridview value modify it and add it to other sum

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have this point of sale system. ive been doing this for days now and i cant really seem to make it work. I have this discount checkbox that when you clicked
its supposed to do this:

1. Check all products with "D" on it and sum its total price and list it to totaldiscountablesales.Text
2. Show the total discounted price in discount.Text
3. The subtotal should still be all the sum of the price regardless with D or not.
4. Totaldue should be subtotal - total discounts.

I don't know whats wrong with my code its all I can with my current knowledge now.

[image]

```
private void cbDiscount2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        double Dsum = 0;
        double sumwithoudD = 0;
        double Dsumless20;
        double Dsumless20plussum;

        if (cbDiscount2.Checked == true)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < dgvPOScart.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (dgvPOScart.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString() == "D")
                {
                    Dsum += Convert.ToDouble(dgvPOScart.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                    totaldiscountablesales.Text = Dsum.ToString("0.00");
                    Dsumless20 = Dsum * .20;                     
                    discount.Text = Dsumless20.ToString("0.00");
                }
                else if((dgvPOScart.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString() == ""))
                {                    
                    sumwithoudD += Convert.ToDouble(dgvPOScart.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                }       

            }
            Dsumless20plussum = Dsum + sumwithoudD;               
            totaldue.Text = Dsumless20plussum.ToString("0.00");               
        }
        else if (cbDiscount2.Checked == false)
        {
              for (int i = 0; i < dgvPOScart.Rows.Count; ++i)
              {
                 sum += Convert.ToDouble(dgvPOScart.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                 subtotal.Text = sum.ToString("0.00");
                 totaldue.Text = sum.ToString("0.00");
              }                 
        } 

    }
```

Comment: That's not how you spell penicillin.

Comment: i know and im sorry :v

Comment: It would probably help if you told us what numbers are right and which ones are wrong, and if they are wrong, what should the number be.  `subtotal should still be all the sum of the price regardless with D or not` But it looks like you only increment the "sum" variable in the else-if block.

Comment: edited it thank you

Comment: `dgvPOScart.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString() == null` will never be `true`. If `Value` is null, `ToString()` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @Anderson thank you sir ive edited it to =""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably made this more complicated than it needs to be.  Try is like this, where you only keep track of the two totals you care about: total cart and the discounted items:

```
decimal cartTotal = 0;
decimal discountTotal = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dgvPOScart.Rows.Count; ++i) {
  cartTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(dgvPOScart.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
  if (cbDiscount2.Checked && dgvPOScart.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString() == "D") {
    discountTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(dgvPOScart.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
  }
}

totaldue.Text = string.Format("{0}", cartTotal - (discountTotal * .2M));
subtotal.Text = string.Format("{0}", cartTotal);
totaldiscountablesales.Text = string.Format("{0}", discountTotal);
discount.Text = string.Format("{0}", discountTotal * .2M);
```

When dealing with monetary values, you should use the Decimal type instead of Double since precision matters.

Comment: @Thank you so much sir it work and your code is more effcient. if you dont mind me asking sir how can i make the format of the prices to 0.00? because its showing 0.000. Again sir thank you so much.

Comment: @FutureDev You can format it a million ways with string.Format.  To just make two decimal places, try `subtotal.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", cartTotal);`

Comment: Thanks sir i dont use decimal because of that but now ill use it when its about money. Thank you sir Lars!